# Java String format issue. two elements after a dot

Tags: java, double

I have a custom keyboard and I try to convert input value like a double. For example, input 1 is 0.01. My main goal is to  show only two elements after a dot, always, but if the input is 80 then result is 0.8 ,but I want it to be 0.80
Here is my source

```
 userEntered = userEntered + pressedString;
 Double dd = Double.parseDouble(userEntered);
 dd = dd / 100;
 amountText.setText(dd.toString());
```

I clearing input value like this in a button click

```
if (userEntered.length() > 0) {
    userEntered = userEntered.substring(0, userEntered.length() - 1);
    Double dd = Double.parseDouble(userEntered);
    dd = dd / 100;
    amountText.setText(dd.toString());
}
```

How I can solve a problem? Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

You can use DecimalFormat class in Java.

Please have look at
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Example :

```
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
System.out.println(f.format(yourDouble));
```